# Database add item to list view?

Tags: java, android

I download this database script and i was wondering how can i convert it to instead add a item to a list view.. its a really easy understandable database code..

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/AABDatabase.zip

Thats the source for it..

also im guessing it could be in here??

```
/**
 * retrieves a row from the database with the id number in the corresponding
 * user entry field
 */
private void retrieveRow()
{
    try
    {
        // The ArrayList that holds the row data
        ArrayList<Object> row;
        // ask the database manager to retrieve the row with the given rowID
        row = db.getRowAsArray(Long.parseLong(updateIDField.getText().toString()));

        // update the form fields to hold the retrieved data
        updateTextFieldOne.setText((String)row.get(1));
        updateTextFieldTwo.setText((String)row.get(2));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Retrieve Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the items from database to a ListView you can have an ArrayList

1.)    `ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();`

2.)    Fetch items from database and add them to ArrayList

```
        if(c.getCount() > 0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount() - 1; i++) {
                arrList.add(c.getString(0));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
```

3.) `Then populate the Adapter with the ArrayList(arrList).`

4.) `And fill the ListView with the Adapter.`

Comment: i don't quite understand.. could you send me a modified version of the code

Comment: It would be better for you to look at some ListView examples and then try to populate what I have answered. Thanks.